# Efficient way of assigning of IF conditions provided in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a set of IF conditions provided in tabular form. E.g.

```
  rule_id number          colour                    shape
1       1    200                                         
2       2    100                                 triangle
3       3     NA             red                         
4       4     NA ‘blue’,‘orange’                rectangle
5       5     NA           green Not(‘triangle’,‘square’)
6       6     NA
```

The table needs to be read as follows (in pseudo code):

IF `number = 200` THEN `rule_id = 1`

IFELSE `number = 100 AND shape = triangle` THEN `rule_id = 2`

IFELSE `colour = red` THEN `rule_id = 3` 
.....

I am then interested in categorizing the rows in a dataset according to these rules. E.g. (`rule_id` is the result of the categorization)

```
  number colour    shape rule_id
1    100    red triangle       2
2    200 yellow     none       1
3    300   blue     none       6
4    200   none     none       1
5    100    red   square       3
6    500  green   circle       5
7    400  green   square       6
8    600   none     none       6
```

In order to do so, I used a FOR loop running through all rules (I categorize 1st all rows that meet the conditions of `rule_id = 1`, then go to the next iteration for `rule_id = 2`). This seems unfortunately a very slow procedure (the dimensions of both my rules table and my dataset are much larger).

Is there a more optimal way of doing this?
And, also how do I best deal with the `Not` in the rules table?

The code I used is (maybe not a beauty...):

```
rules = data.frame(rule_id = 1:6,
               number = c(200, 100, rep(NA,4)),
               colour = c('', '', 'red', paste(sQuote('blue'), sQuote('orange'), sep = ','), 'green', ''),
               shape = c('', 'triangle','','rectangle', paste(paste('Not(', sQuote('triangle'), sep = ''), 
                                                              paste(sQuote('square'), ')', sep = ''), sep = ','), ''),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data = data.frame(number = c(100, 200, 300, 200, 100, 500, 400, 600),
              colour = c('red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'none', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'none'),
              shape = c('triangle', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'square', 'circle', 'square', 'none'),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


data$rule_id = NA

nbrRules = nrow(rules)

for (j in 1:nbrRules){

  data$rule_id[is.na(data$rule_id)
          & (data$number == rules$number[j]
             | is.na(rules$number[j]))
          & ((apply(as.data.frame(data$colour), 
                    1, 
                    function(x) grepl(x, rules$colour[j]))
              & (!grepl("Not", rules$colour[j])))
             | (apply(as.data.frame(data$colour), 
                      1, 
                      function(x) !grepl(x, rules$colour[j]))
                & (grepl("Not", rules$colour[j])))
             | (rules$colour[j] == ""))
          & ((apply(as.data.frame(data$shape), 
                    1, 
                    function(x) grepl(x, rules$shape[j]))
              & (!grepl("Not", rules$shape[j])))
             | (apply(as.data.frame(data$shape), 
                      1, 
                      function(x) !grepl(x, rules$shape[j]))
                & (grepl("Not", rules$shape[j])))
             | (rules$shape[j] == ""))] = rules$rule_id[j]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I haven't had time to implement @alexis_laz his suggestion, but he made me realize that maybe some time could be gained by looping through the rules in reverse `for (j in nbrRules:1)` instead of `for (j in 1:nbrRules)` as this allows me to remove the `is.na(data$rule_id)` filter from

```
data$rule_id[is.na(data$rule_id)
          & (data$number == rules$number[j]
             | is.na(rules$number[j]))
          ....
```

On the actual dataset I applied it, it led to a small gain in time (from 3.978148 mins to 3.972381 mins).

I also realized that my comment was wrong and that  @Oliver Frost his `ifelse` suggestion would not lead to more conditions. Changing the code to this however, led to a slower program (4.079141 mins on my actual dataset)

```
for (j in 1:nbrRules){

  data$rule_id = ifelse(is.na(data$rule_id)
                        & (data$number == rules$number[j]
                           | is.na(rules$number[j]))
                        & ((apply(as.data.frame(data$colour), 
                                  1, 
                                  function(x) grepl(x, rules$colour[j]))
                            & (!grepl("Not", rules$colour[j])))
                           | (apply(as.data.frame(data$colour), 
                                    1, 
                                    function(x) !grepl(x, rules$colour[j]))
                              & (grepl("Not", rules$colour[j])))
                           | (rules$colour[j] == ""))
                        & ((apply(as.data.frame(data$shape), 
                                  1, 
                                  function(x) grepl(x, rules$shape[j]))
                            & (!grepl("Not", rules$shape[j])))
                           | (apply(as.data.frame(data$shape), 
                                    1, 
                                    function(x) !grepl(x, rules$shape[j]))
                              & (grepl("Not", rules$shape[j])))
                           | (rules$shape[j] == ""))
                        ,rules$rule_id[j],
                        data$rule_id)
}
```

Comment: Should the second step of the pseudocode be `IFELSE number = 100 AND shape = triangle THEN rule_id = 2`  ?

Comment: Does `?ifelse` give you what you need?

Comment: I believe the format of the `rules` "data.frame" is a bit inconvenient to work with. You could try transforming it to a multidimensional array, which you can -simply- subset with the `data` "data.frame". To illustrate, here is a hardcoded attempt: `myNumbers = c("100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "none"); myColours = c("red", "blue", "orange", "green", "yellow", "none"); myShapes = c("triangle", "rectangle", "square", "circle", "none"); myArray = array(0L, c(length(myNumbers), length(myColours), length(myShapes)), list(myNumbers, myColours, myShapes))` (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) `myArray[, , ] = 6L; myArray[, "green", setdiff(myShapes, c("triangle", "square"))] = 5L; myArray[, c("blue", "orange"), "rectangle"] = 4L; myArray[, "red", ] = 3L; myArray["100", , "triangle"] = 2L; myArray["200", , ] = 1L`. And, then, you can subset as `myArray[as.matrix(data[1:3])]`

Comment: Thanks for the reactions. @G5W, indeed, the second step of the pseudocode was incorrect. @Oliver Frost, I might be mistaken, but it feels like there are too many conditions to be formulated for using `?ifelse`. @alexis_laz, I am currently trying your suggestion, but I am a bit stuck for the moment when having to select an entire dimension of `myArray` (e.g. in `myArray["200", , ]` the  entire second and third dimensions are to be selected). I don't want to hardcode this, but make use of the fact that `""` in a row in the rules dataset means that the entire dimension is to be selected.